# Where to revoke access in Google, for the applications I gave permission to access my data?

Tags: permissions, office-365, access

In google I have a page where I can revoke access to applications that have permission to access my data etc.

I dont know where to find this in accesspoint (office365).

Can you help me find this?

[image: Google Revoke Access]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same is possible in Office 365. Just go to your site collection where the app resides that you want to revoke access. Go to Site Settings, and in the User and Persmissions group, follow the link to **Site app permissions**.

[image]

From that page you can easely revoke access to any app within your site collection.

[image]

You can also access the page directly using the link https://mySiteCollection.company.com/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its strange that my native application which I made is not registered as one of the apps that has access. How is that possible?

Comment: Can you also explain me how to do this for OneDrive for Business?